# Monitor Java Heap on a Centos Server via Telegraf/Grafana

Tags: centos, java, logstash, heapspace, telegraf

How to Monitor Java Heap usage on  centos server using Telegraf and Grafana? This monitoring is particularly for Logstash process running on the server. I tried to use JSTAT to get data, but it has lot of numbers which needs manipulation to obtain heapsize. Is there a straightforward way to let telegraf send out heap size info?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the Prometheus JMX exporter? Prometheus integrates with both Telegraf and Grafana nicely.